# React Hooks: компонент Dropdown с внешней загрузкой данных

Tags: reactjs, компоненты, react-hook

Хочу реализовать компонент `dropdown` (на react hooks) в который контент выпадающего списка загружается через функцию-параметр `dataSource`, т.е. что-то типа такого:

```
function Dropdown({ dataSource }) {
  if(!Array.isArray(dataSource) {
    assert.func(dataSource)
  }
  const [dataItems, setDataItems] = useState(undefined)

  useEffect(function resetDataItemsByDataSource() {
    setDataItems(typeof dataSource === 'function' ? undefined : Array.from(dataSource))
  }, [dataSource])

  useEffect(function initDataItems() {
    if(dataItems != null || typeof dataSource !== 'function') {
      return
    }
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => dataSource())
      .then(items => {
        // how detect that dataSource is changed???
        if(isDataSourceChanged()) {
          return
        }
        setDataItems(Array.from(items))
      })
  }, [dataSource, dataItems])

  // . . .
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, как определить, что когда данные из `dataSource` загрузились, то мы работаем все еще с тем же `dataSource`(`ds`),  с которым начинали загрузку данных? Т.е. возможна такая ситуация, что изначально был указан `ds1`, данные начали грузиться, потом клиент указал `ds2`, данные начали грузиться с него, загрузка с `ds2` была завершена и успешно сохранена в `dataItems`, после этого закончилась загрузка с `ds1` и мы НЕ должны перезаписать последние актуальные данные с `ds2`. Как в хуках реакта наиболее корректно обработать этот кейс? Возможно стоит каждое изменение `dataSource`  сохранять в `useRef`, а в `then`'е обработки результата загрузки сравнивать значение из `useRef` со значением `dataSource` на момент начала загрузки? (что-то типа такого):

```
  const dsRef = useRef(null) // <====

  useEffect(function initDataItems() {
    dsRef.current = dataSource // <====
    if(dataItems != null || typeof dataSource !== 'function') {
      return
    }
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => dataSource())
      .then(items => {
        if(dsRef.current !== dataSource) {  // <====
          return
        }
        setDataItems(Array.from(items))
      })
  }, [dataSource, dataItems])
```

Или есть более корректный способ?

P.S. функция `resetDataItemsByDataSource` была выделена в отдельный `useEffect` для того чтобы при изменении `dataSource` был сброшен в `undefined` значение `dataItems` и отработало условие:

```
if(dataItems != null || typeof dataSource !== 'function') {
  return
}
```

P.S.S. В этом всем мне не нравится, что получается как-то запутано и сложно, что наводит на мысли, что реализовано либо не правильно либо не оптимально.